# jQuery Find the specific text in the page

Tags: jquery, redirect, find

I want to redirect the user automatically into another page if this text exist 'Shopping Cart is Empty'. I found this jQuery :contains() Selector and test on it but It didn't work. Here's my code:

```
<div class="page-title">
<h1>Shopping Cart is Empty</h1>
</div>

<script>
 $( "div.page-title:contains('Shopping Cart is Empty')".window.location.replace("http://www.another-page.com");
</script>
```

Comment: you need an Event that call your "function" e.g. .load, .ready, .click

Comment: You need to put it in an `if else` statement and as @TimoJungblut already said, put it inside a `.ready` or on the end of the page.

Comment: @TimoJungblut I am not good with jQuery event call and still learning the basics, can you help me re-construct my code?

Comment: @kirk check my answer with DEMO

Comment: @kirk palaSH added a good example for you

Comment: @TimoJungblut yeah it works too! I tested your answer and with palaSH! Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**Fiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/8d7R9/)

```
$(function () {
    var len = $("div.page-title h1").filter(function () {
        return this.innerHTML === "Shopping Cart is Empty";
    }).length;
    if (len > 0) {
        window.location.replace("http://www.another-page.com");
    }
});
```

Comment: What's the difference between this and @palaѕн 's answer?

Comment: @Tushar Can I ask for another help, this is still related to post I made above.

Comment: @ErickBest he uses `$(this).text()` i used `this.innerHTML` which is faster and he was using `.length()` but correct is `.length`

Comment: @kirk yeah sure you can ask .

Comment: @Tushar Thanks. Actually I have this code that is in OOP form 
<div class="page-title">
    <h1><?php echo $this->__('Shopping Cart is Empty') ?></h1>
</div>
My problem is how can I transform the code you gave to fit into this code? Sorry, a bit not good in OOP.

Comment: @kirk what do you want ??

Comment: @TusharGupta Sorry about my problem, anyway thank you for the help :)

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
// Call the function when DOM is ready
$(function () {

    // Check if page title has a text using length
    var len = $("div.page-title h1").filter(function () {
        return $(this).text() === "Shopping Cart is Empty";
    }).length;

    // If the text is there on the page, redirect to another page
    if (len > 0) {
        window.location.replace("http://www.another-page.com");
    }
});
```

Comment: @palasH I tested it now, but still not redirecting to another page

Comment: `.length` not `.length()`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if($("div.page-title :contains(Shopping Cart is Empty)").length > 0){
    window.location.href = "http://www.another-page.com";
}
```

[Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/387KA/1/)

Answer (score 1):

```
if($('.page-title h1')text()=="Shopping Cart is Empty"){
```

window.location.replace("http://www.another-page.com");
}

Answer (score 1):

Of course make sure your Codes are inside jQuery load function or something like.

```
$(function(){

..Your Code here...
})
```

Then, you may try to use the `indexOf()` to be more specific.

Something like:

```
if( $("div.page-title h1").text().indexOf('Empty') !=-1 ){

window.location.href="http://www.goodle.com";

}
```

So, all in all it will be something like:

```
$(function(){

if( $("div.page-title h1").text().indexOf('Empty') !=-1 ){

    window.location.href="http://www.goodle.com";

    }

})
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

you can also use `contains` like this

```
<script>
    if ($( "div.page-title:contains('Shopping Cart is Empty')").length > 0) {
        window.location.replace("http://www.another-page.com");
    }
</script>
```

the `content` element returns all the divs element objects that contains the specified string. so check for length then redirect.